# How to run an external application from Qt program?

Tags: qt, qprocess

I'm trying to run an external exe from my Qt app. It's an "autorun application" and it has three buttons: one is suppose to run an external installer which is an .exe app.

I tried:

```
system("Setup.exe")
```

It works but it displays terminal when running the installer. I also tried:

```
QProcess::startDetached("Setup.exe");
```

and also tried:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->start("Setup.exe");
```

but neither works (nothing happens, there are no logs in the console output as well). Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I try to check all possible problems. This code will start your process or show why it does not want to work.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString pathToExecutable = "c:\\Apps\\MyApp\\Setup.exe";

    // Check the path string was written correctly and Qt can see it
    QFileInfo fileInfo(pathToExecutable);

    QProcess process;

    if (fileInfo.exists())
    {
        if(fileInfo.isExecutable())
        {
            QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::errorOccurred,
                &process, [&]()
            {
                qWarning() << process.errorString();
            });

            /*
            Qt doc:
            To set a working directory, call setWorkingDirectory().
            By default, processes are run in the current
            working directory of the calling process.
            */
            QString executableDir = fileInfo.absolutePath();
            process.setWorkingDirectory(executableDir);

            QString absuluteExecutableFilePath = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();

            /* 
            Even if QFileInfo see your file, QProcess may not run it,
            if the path contains spaces
            */           
            if (absuluteExecutableFilePath.contains(' '));
            {
                absuluteExecutableFilePath.prepend("\"").append("\"");
            }

            // If you need to check errors, use start(), but not startDetached()
            process.start(absuluteExecutableFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            qWarning() << "Given file is not executable";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning() << "File path does not exist or is set incorrectly";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It turned out it wasn't working because the app for QProcess needed admin priviliges. Thanks for the help.