# Using QProcess to call an external program, with arguments

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I have a exe folder located in one folder, and then all of my config files in another. In order to run the program:

- I need to direct the terminal to the config file folder
- Then run the exe folder, with arguments.

Shown below, I have this working correctly using system calls, but I need a system agnostic way of doing this.

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    std::system("cd Path_To_ConfigFolder & Absolute_Path_To_Exe RunFile.txt > logfile.txt");
}
```

The above works great. Although it only works on Windows.. so I did some research on using QProcess to create a more system agnostic way.. and no matter what I try I can't seem to get this to work. See below:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    p.setWorkingDirectory("Path_To_ConfigFolder");
    params << " RunFile.txt > logfile.txt";
    p.start("Absolute_Path_To_Exe", params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
}
```

Note: For the above example (using QProcess), I am `\\` for all my paths, and all my paths are correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to check all possible errors of course. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969455/how-to-run-an-external-application-from-qt-program/60973204#60973204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of executable would be starting with `".\"` if it is in local folder to be system-agnostic. Linux shell and PowerShell require that.

">" - output redirection isn't an argument of process, that won't work. You have to redirect output channel to your or a secondary process.

```
p.setStandardOutputFile("log_file.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Swift . How do I direct to the output file inside of p.start()?

Comment: @TBCoder92 Have a look at [`QProcess::setStandardOutputFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputFile).

Comment: Placed `p.setStandardOutputFile(AbsPathToLogFile.txt)` above `p.start()` and removed space before `RunFile.txt` . Doing these all worked, thanks for the help!